# is it possible to share code between two git servers?

Tags: git, github, gitea

I'm trying to share code between two gits, not between two repositories inside a single git, but two different git servers.

I have a github account, and I have my own git server, thanks to Raspberry and Gitea. I want to share code between this two git servers, one on github and one in localhost.

I want to share pushes between both git, and I've tried to follow this tutorial

https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories

But, when I try to push to localhost, I have:

```
fatal: repository 'http://localhost:port/user/repo.git' not found
```

when I've tried to create the same repo from Web Interface on localhost, I found problems: "Repository already exists"

I think I've tried to run before walk...

Comment: Just add the two different remotes to your repo, you can push to both of them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+remotes

Comment: What do you mean by "a git"?   To share code between two git repositories, you need to fetch, or make a bundle.  If the repos are on the same host, you can use local methods as a transport mechanism.  If the repos are on different hosts, you need to use some some non-local transport (eg, http, or sneaker net).  But it sounds like you just want `git fetch` and `git push`

Comment: I have a github repository and a gitea repository on localhost. I would like to push to both servers at one time. I think I found yesterday how I can add two different remotes as @jonrsharpe said previously, but I failed

Comment: Then please [edit] to expand on what you tried and what "failed" means.